# How do you assert that an exception is thrown if it has already been consumed/handled/caught

Tags: java, junit

Let's say I test a class method that is reliant on another method that we do not want or can not test directly, which handles a checked exception, in the following manner:

```
public class A {

    public void process(){
        if (isProcessingSuccessful()){
            LOG.info("Success");
        }
        else {
            LOG.error("Fail");
        }
    }

    private boolean isProcessingSuccessful(){
        try{
            doSomeOtherStuff();
            return true;
        }
        catch (Exception e){
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Now, if I have a test class testing for the A#process(), like:

```
@Test
public void shouldFailDueToCommandGatewayError() {
    A a = new A();
    // setting up preconditions

    //testing here
    a.process();

    //Now, assert exception was thrown during the course of a.process() execution, something like
    exception.expect(NullPointerException.class);
    // ?? how to do that?
}
```

TLTD: It is possible to write separate test for isProcessingSuccessful() or do something similar, but let's say that method is not accessible for testing, like it's private in a library?

Given the above constraints, is there any way to write a test in a way that ascertains the exception was thrown in the underlying method as above?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, junit can't tell the exception was thrown, since it gets eaten by the code being tested. For you to detect what happened here you would have to check what was written to the log. Replace the appender with something that holds onto what is written to it, then the test can verify what was written to it at the end of the test.

Comment: At least someone who read OPs code (not like the other three -.-). OP could also try to mock `doSomeOtherStuff()` (when it uses stuff from a different class) and force the exception there. **"Alternatively make the private method public so you can test it directly."** - Bah, no, don't do such stuff :/

Comment: IMHO, if other three folks interpret the answer the same and wrong independently, it shows the question is not as clear as it looked like. OBVIOUSLY the 4th one after the series of accusations would try to interpret the question differently. Thus I don't understand your sigh.

Comment: @Tom: I removed the part you complained about since the OP already covers that in the question.

Comment: Well, I do already have a log analyzer and that's exactly how my current test works. I just wanted to double-check that an exception of a desired type has also been thrown on the way.

Comment: @NathanHughes Thanks :). Changing code for testing is always a delicate matter :).

Comment: @NikolasCharalambidis *"it shows the question is not as clear as it looked like"* - Only if you ignore the posted code and just read the title (and that's the reason for my disappointment, because three people did that). And this doesn't have anything to do with interpretation of the question, the code is _very_ clear.

Comment: @Tom *"you ignore the posted code"* - It's just your assumption. I don't know about others, but I have read the whole question. Please, weight your words.

Answer (score 0):

You can't catch the exception again which have been already consumed. The only way is to catch the exception with the test method as described below.

Annote the test method that is supposed to fail with `@Test` and use the `expected` parameter for the expected exception.

```
@Test(expected = NullPointerException.class)
public void shouldFailDueToCommandGatewayError() {

    // something that throws NullPointerException
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
@Test(expected = NullPointerException.class)
```

This basically says:

If this test quits with a NullPointerException then everything is as expected. Otherwise this test will fail.

Comment: And can you explain why you think the exception would reach the test class although it is clearly visible that OP already catches it in the code?

Answer (score -1):

```
@Test(expected = NullPointerException.class)
```

has been mentioned already. This feature came wuth JUnit 4. Before that and if you want to do want to check more than just a particular type of exception being thrown, you can do something like this:

```
try {
    doSometing("", "");
    fail("exception expected");
}
catch(IllegalArgumentException iae) {
    assertEquals("check message", "parameter a must not be empty", iae.getMessage());
    assertNull("check non-existance of cause", iae.getCause());
}
try {
    doSometing("someval", "");
    fail("exception expected");
}
catch(IllegalArgumentException iae) {
    assertEquals("check message", "parameter b must not be empty", iae.getMessage());
    assertNull("check non-existance of cause", iae.getCause());
}
```

This is particular useful if the same type of exception is thrown and you want to ensure that the "correct" exception is thrown with a given combination of parameters.

Comment: The first suggestion obviously doesn't work here and your second suggestion has several compile time issues.

Comment: @Tom Why should there be compile time issues? This is JUnit 3 as you should be well aware if you have read my answer.

Comment: JUnit3 is stone age. And your code repeatedly calls the production code. That is bad practice as well. And if you want to know why code doesnt compile - then read it more carefully or run it through a compiler.

Comment: *"Why should there be compile time issues?"* - Since you don't like to read your own code: you called your exception variable `iae` and then access it with `e`. And I'm a aware that these methods (`assertEquals`, `assertNull` and `fail`) are part of normal testing libraries (not only JUnit).

Comment: The main issue remains: the exception isn't propagated to the caller, therefore you neither can't "expect" the exception nor catch it.